# Owncloud did not recognize new folders

Tags: linux, raspbian

I have installed owncloud on my raspberry PI. I use my external HDD as database for my owncloud. Yesterday I disconnect my HDD from PI and connect it to PC, it is much easier to create and fill folders over PC. I copied few folders with photos, films, videos etc... When i plugged HDD to PI, I can see in my owncloud every folder (photo, films, videos), but for example in pictures, there is no files or folders. When I check it over terminal, I can see everything. Why can I reach some folders and pictures not?

Comment: Owncloud maintains a cache of stuff; maybe by changing files "out of band" this cache is now stale and may need rebuilding.  See the `occ` command ( https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/admin_manual/configuration_server/occ_command.html ) on how to do this from the command line.

Comment: Hi. I used command from "Maintenance Commands" section. It is not solve the problem. It is interesting, because some folders are reachable and some not.  Do you have any other idea how to solve this issue?